# Laravel + Shopify inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, shopify

I'm using following package : 'osiset/Basic-Shopify-API' and need bulk update products by location.
It's only possible with GraphQL. This function should work : 
 inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation [Shopify documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/graphql/reference/mutation/inventorybulkadjustquantityatlocation?api[version]=2020-04)

```
    $shop = 'example.myshopify.com';
    $token = 'shppa_admin_api_token';

    / Create options for the API
    $options = new Options();
    $options->setVersion('2020-04');

     // Create the client and session
    $api = new BasicShopifyAPI($options);
    $api->setSession(new Session($shop, $token));


     $products[0]['inventoryItemId'] = '33125243617303';
    $products[0]['availableDelta'] = 2000;

    $result = $api->graph(
        'mutation inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation($inventoryItemAdjustments: InventoryAdjustItemInput!,$locationId: ID!) 
                 {inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation(inventoryItemAdjustments: $InventoryAdjustItemInput, locationId: $locationId) {userErrors {field message } inventoryLevels { id }}}',
        ['inventoryItemAdjustments' => 

            $products

        ],

    );
```

But I don't understand how to use it. Could anyone help me ?

Comment: pass ONE, complex, prepared object(array) as `inventoryItemAdjustments` mutation variable

Answer (score 0):

Now it works. It's a challenge to understand GraphQL queries if you never used them before.

Here are some more information :

https://www.shopify.com/partners/blog/multi-location_and_graphql

```
 $locationId = "gid://shopify/Location/1";

    $inventoryItemAdjustments1['locationId'] = $locationId;
    $inventoryItemAdjustments1['inventoryItemAdjustments']['inventoryItemId'] = 'gid://shopify/InventoryItem/1';
    $inventoryItemAdjustments1['inventoryItemAdjustments']['availableDelta'] = 500;

    $result = $api->graph('mutation inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation($inventoryItemAdjustments: [InventoryAdjustItemInput!]!, $locationId: ID!) 
    {inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation(inventoryItemAdjustments: $inventoryItemAdjustments, locationId: $locationId) {userErrors { field message }}}',
    $inventoryItemAdjustments1    
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not so good examples (hardcoded values, aliases - not real life examples) ... graphql variables should be used and they should match mutation requirements ('root' parameters), in this case `locationId` and `inventoryItemAdjustments` (array of objects).

You can test this mutation in graphiql/playground using 'query variables' defined like this:

```
{
  locationId: "gid://shopify/Location/1",
  inventoryItemAdjustments: [
    { 
      'inventoryItemId': 'gid://shopify/InventoryItem/1',
      'availableDelta': 500
    },
    { 
      'inventoryItemId': 'gid://shopify/InventoryItem/2',
      'availableDelta': 100
    }
  ]
}
```

... so using php (associative arrays are encoded to json as objects - explicitely declared for readability) it should look more like this:

```
 $locationId = "gid://shopify/Location/1";
 $inventoryItemAdjustments = [];
 $inventoryItemAdjustments[] = (object)[
   'inventoryItemId' => 'gid://shopify/InventoryItem/1',
   'availableDelta'] => 500;
 ];
 $inventoryItemAdjustments[] = (object)[
   'inventoryItemId' => 'gid://shopify/InventoryItem/2',
   'availableDelta'] => 100;
 ];

 $variables = (object)[
   'locationId' => $locationId;
   'inventoryItemAdjustments' => $inventoryItemAdjustments
 ];

 $result = $api->graph('mutation inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation($inventoryItemAdjustments: [InventoryAdjustItemInput!]!, $locationId: ID!) 
    {inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation(inventoryItemAdjustments: $inventoryItemAdjustments, locationId: $locationId) {userErrors { field message }}}',
    $variables
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to show another library that uses this and expand on the last example.

I am using a slightly different library for graphql:
https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-php-api/

Updating the inventory like it was posted here shows a  [statusCode:GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response:private] => 200
So it seems to work but does not reflect in updated inventory. :(

Checking at /admin/products/inventory?location_id=62241177806&query=F11_27781195
would not show the new inventory.
I am using the inventoryid correctly (not product or variantid).

```
 $inventoryItemAdjustments = array();
 
 $inventoryItemAdjustments[] = (object)[
   'inventoryItemId' => 'gid://shopify/InventoryItem/43151435235534',
   'availableDelta' => 500
 ];
 $inventoryItemAdjustments[] = (object)[
   'inventoryItemId' => 'gid://shopify/InventoryItem/43151435268302',
   'availableDelta' => 500
 ];

 $variables = array(
   'locationId' => ConfigClass::$locationId,
   'inventoryItemAdjustments' => $inventoryItemAdjustments
 );

$graphqlquery='mutation inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation($inventoryItemAdjustments: [InventoryAdjustItemInput!]!, $locationId: ID!) 
    {inventoryBulkAdjustQuantityAtLocation(inventoryItemAdjustments: $inventoryItemAdjustments, locationId: $locationId) {userErrors { field message }}}';

$response = $client->query(['query' => $graphqlquery, 'variables' => $variables]);
```

Deleting a product works (and is a good test if the library is initialized well):

```
$query = <<<QUERY
  mutation {
    productDelete(input: {id: "gid://shopify/Product/6975310463182"})
    {
      deletedProductId
    }
  }
QUERY;
$response = $client->query(["query" => $query]);

print_r($response);
die;
```